# Как вывести полную информацию в колонку таблицы javafx

Tags: java, tableview

ситуация следующая, не могу никак сделать так, чтобы в ячейку выводилась полная информация из БД, на данный момент только часть, остальная часть просто уходить за область ячейки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы та информация, которая не попадает, переходила на новую строчку?